# Sync folders on Vagrant for Windows doesn't work

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

I have a Windows 10 host machine and I want to create a virtual Windows 10 machine using VirtualBox and Vagrant. Everything works great, except that I've configured to sync a folder between the host and the guest and this doesn't work. There are no errors in the console.

Interesting thing is that when I open my VM in VirtualBox management UI - I can see that the synced folder configuration is there. If I stop the machine from the UI and click on the "automount" option and then start it again - everything works as expected.

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "Microsoft/EdgeOnWindows10"
  config.vm.guest = :windows
  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"      

  config.vm.synced_folder "../../setup", "/setup"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.gui = true
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "32"]
   end
end
```

Any thoughts about what might be the reason? I've checked other similar questions, but nothing seems to be my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `vboxguestadditions` into your VM.